# pywinauto correct element to select click row in table

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

Trying to get pywinauto to automate a repetitive task. I've managed to load the file I want to print into the printer software. Now all I'm trying to do is to get pywinauto to click on a specific line in the list to select a file like is shown in the picture below. The purpose is two-fold:

- clear the list of past printed files by iterating over all the table rows (issuing a DELETE keystroke for each)
- once a new file is loaded, select it like is shown in the image below to be able to start printing (via a external pedal)

The output for pywinauto `print_control_identifiers()` can be seen in this [link](https://pastebin.com/mXhM0n2S).

My guess is that I would want something below `'HeaderTaskName3'`, but not seeing any children in the tree and when I tried `drawing_outline()` for what I thought was the ListView item, it outlines the whole table. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could try with some GUI inspector tool to get the structure and name of the GUI items. I have had some success with [SWAPY](https://github.com/pywinauto/SWAPY/releases). It is not maintained anymore, but last time I tried it, it was more useful than the newer [py_inspect](https://github.com/pywinauto/py_inspect).

Comment: awesome, thanks np8, will give it a go!

Comment: ugh, tried SWAPY but it crashes when trying to select the row :/

Comment: Did you try both 32bit and 64bit versions? If yes, maybe you have better luck with the py_inspect.

Comment: py_inspect doesn't really show anything interesting

Comment: Did you try both 32-bit and 64-bit SWAPY? I think I also experienced some crashes but it was still usable. I used it to make automation scripts for one old 32-bit GUI.

Comment: ok, yes, 32 bit didn't crash! but it also didn't show anything that I found useful. Why are some programs like this one so hard to get the elements for?